# Responsive position:absolute for button

Tags: position, absolute, responsiveness

I have an image that has a button with position absolute on the right side. The button should stay in place when the window is resized.

I could do this with silly media queries after every small screen change but that doesn't seem right.

What would be the best solution? I have also created a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/5t1zu6px/2/

```
.post-image {   
    width:40%;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}
button {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:10%;
    right:-9%;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an unordered list. See solution below:

### HTML

From:

```
<div class="post-image">
<img src="http://no11.ee/hulk/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/meeskond.png">
<button>BUTTON</button> 
</div>
```

To:

```
<div class="pst-img">
<ul>
<li><img src="http://no11.ee/hulk/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/meeskond.png" /></li>
<li><button>BUTTON</button></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

### CSS

From:

```
.post-wrap {
  width:100%;
  height:377px;
}
.post-image {   
 width:40%;
 position:relative;
float:left;
}
button {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:10%;
  right:-9%;
}
.post-text {
  width:60%;
  float:left;
  text-align:center;
}
p {
  padding:40px;   
}
```

To:

```
.pst-img ul li { 
  display:inline-block; padding-right:100px; list-style:none; }
.post-wrap {
  width:100%;
  height:377px;
}
.post-text {
  width:60%;
  float:left;
  text-align:center;
}
p {
  padding:40px;   
}
```

JSFiddle Link Update: http://jsfiddle.net/5t1zu6px/7/

Hopefully this helps!